# How to fetch a Backbone.js model by something other than the ID?

Tags: backbone.js

Backbone.js's default, RESTful approach to fetching a model by the ID is easy and straight-forward. However, I can't seem to find any examples of fetching a model by a different attribute. How can I fetch a Backbone.js model by a different attribute?

```
var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '/widgets',
    fetchByName: function(){ ... }
});
var foowidget = new Widget({name: 'Foo'});
foowidget.fetchByName();
```

Comment: Is the name going to be unique on the server?  Then you could use 'name' as the id by setting `idAttribute: 'name'` in your model. Then just fetch normally; but that is assuming the endpoint for an instance is '/widgets/<name>'.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke I was planning on using both, but that's good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try doing something like this on your `base model` definition or on demand when calling fetch.

```
model.fetch({ data: $.param({ someParam: 12345}) });
```

In your case, along the lines of.

```
var Widget = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.name = options.name;        
    },
    urlRoot: '/widgets',
    fetchByName: function(){ 
        this.fetch({ data: $.param({ name: this.name }) }) 
    }
});

var foowidget = new Widget({name: 'Foo'});
foowidget.fetchByName();
```

Comment: You should probably be returning `this.fetch(...)` inside the `fetchByName` method so you can attach `.then()`, `.done()`, and `.fail()` callbacks to it.

Comment: Absolutely. I was just showing how it can be done using a different parameter.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to override Backbone.sync() method, either for all classes or for just your class. However, presumably your goal is to override fetch for just a single model.  One way to do that is to directly call jQuery.ajax(...), and on success, take the response and set that, e.g.

```
fetchByName: function() {
   var self = this;

    $.ajax({
      url: self.urlRoot+ "?name="+this.get('name'),
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
          self.set(data);
      }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the model is part of a collection you can use where() to pull out the models matching some criteria.

See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where

Comment: Does this fetch the specific model from the server, or select one of many models already returned from the server from a collection-level fetch statement?  If the collection is reasonably sized, that difference probably doesn't matter, but might if the models are very large.

Comment: It's not a model that is usually part of a collection, so this wouldn't work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the approach suggested by 'user645715'. I have adjusted the code to be more versatile. If you add this to a Backbone Model it will allow you to search the server by one or more attributes, and should work as a direct drop-in replacement for `fetch`.

```
fetchByAttributes: function(attributes, callbacks) {

    var queryString = [];
    for(var a in attributes){
        queryString.push( encodeURIComponent(a)+'='+encodeURIComponent(attributes[a]) );
    }
    queryString = '?'+queryString.join('&');

    var self = this;

    $.ajax({
        url: this.urlRoot+queryString,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            self.set(data);
            callbacks.success();
        },
        error: function(data){
            callbacks.error();
        }
    });
}
```

It can be used like this:

```
var page = new Page();
page.fetchByAttributes({slug:slug}, {
    success: function(){
        console.log('fetched something');
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('nothing found');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is simple model.fetch is same as $.ajax in some  way

```
model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "/root/"
});

var Model = new model();

Model.fetch({
    beforeSend: function () {
        console.log("before");
    },
    data: {
        param1: "param1",
        param2: "param2"
    },
    success: function () {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("failure");
    }
});
```