# Express REST get post by slug

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I've this rest api:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Post = mongoose.model('Post'),
    _ = require('lodash');


/**
 * Find post by id
 */
exports.post = function(req, res, next, id) {
   Post.findOne({ '_id': id }, function (err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!post) {
            return next(new Error('Failed to load post ' + id));
        }
        req.post = post;
        next();
    });
};

/**
 * Create a post
 */
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var post = new Post(req.body);
    post.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.jsonp(500,{ error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(post);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Update a post
 */
exports.update = function(req, res) {
    var post = req.post;
    post = _.extend(post, req.body);
    post.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
             res.jsonp(500,{ error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(post);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Delete a post
 */
exports.destroy = function(req, res) {
    var post = req.post;
    post.remove(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            res.jsonp(500,{ error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(post);
        }
    });
};

/**
 * Show a post by id
 */
exports.show = function(req, res) {
    res.jsonp(req.post);
};


/**
 * List of public posts
 */
exports.all = function(req, res) {
    Post.find().sort('-created').exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
           res.jsonp(500,{ error: err.message });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(200,posts);
        }
    });
};
```

with

```
 /* Post */
    var postController = require('../app/controllers/api/post');
    app.post('/api/post', postController.create);
    app.get('/api/post', postController.all);
    app.put('/api/post/:postId', postController.update);
    app.del('/api/post/:postId', postController.destroy);
    app.get('/api/post/:postId', postController.show);

    /* Post Param */
    app.param('postId', postController.post);
```

now I need an other route like
api/post/:slug

but I don't know which way to turn can you give me an hint, please ?
Could be a good way manage with slug instead of id ?

like

```
exports.post = function(req, res, next, slug) {
   Post.findOne({'slug': slug}, function (err, post) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!post) {
            return next(new Error('Failed to load post ' + slug));
        }
        req.post = post;
        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: That will not work. `:postId` and `:slug` are just variable names. The route remains the same.

Comment: I mean using the slug instead of id all in all I've got the slug unique and index

Comment: If you do not need different routes for `:postId` and `:slug`, I do not know what your problem is? Just use given routes for `:slug` then.

Answer (score 3):

Im doing something similar... here is my method...

```
var slugQuery = function(slug){
    var query = {$or: [{slug: slug}]};
    if (slug.match(/^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$/)) {
        query.$or.push({_id: slug});
    }
    return query;
}

exports.getProfile = function (req, res) {
    var slug = req.params.slug; // Can be a slug or _id

    Profile.findOne( slugQuery(slug), function(err, profile){
        if(err){
            // DB Error
            res.status(400);
            res.end();
        }else if(!profile){
            res.status(404);
            res.end();
        }else{
            res.json( profile );
        }
    });
};
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes and not I wanted to avoid such a 'messy code' and as @Amberlamps suggest [Just use given routes for :slug then] so I use slug instead of _id - thanks for the point

Comment: @Whisher Im actually abandoning the approach I mentioned above as just like you, feel its too messy. I also want to remove any disparity/confusion with the use of ids and slugs so I came up with a different solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555612/how-to-fetch-a-backbone-js-model-by-something-other-than-the-id/21417858#21417858